# Toolbar addView not working

Tags: java, android

I need to replace an ordinary `Toolbar` with the own custom one.
I use the following code but nothing is shown:

My `MainActivity` :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private View mView;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mView = 
       LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item_toolbar_main, null);
        mToolbar.addView(mView);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        View view1 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.item_tablayout_item, 
    null);



 view1.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_solved);

        View view2 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.item_tablayout_item, 
  null);



 view2.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_unsolved)
   ;

        try {
            mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(mView);
            mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(mView);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Add crashlitics;
        }

    } }
```

My `XML` of `MainActivity`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.divofmod.quizerfield.Activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_quarter"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            app:contentInsetEnd="@dimen/activity_margin_zero"
            app:contentInsetLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_zero"
            app:contentInsetRight="@dimen/activity_margin_zero"
            app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/activity_margin_zero"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My `XML` of `Toolbar` item :

```
<RelativeLayout 
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoQuizer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_quizer"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logoQuizer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_small"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_small"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_quarter"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/refresh"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sort"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_small"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_quarter"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My `AppTheme`:

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run the code??

Comment: The question is what is wrong? I don't see custom toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by taking the whole  layout `item_toolbar_main` and set it in a `Toolbar` directly in xml without using any `Java` code. So change the `Toolbar` view in your layout `activity_main.xml` to something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_quarter"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        app:contentInsetEnd="@dimen/activity_margin_zero"
        app:contentInsetLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_zero"
        app:contentInsetRight="@dimen/activity_margin_zero"
        app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/activity_margin_zero"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

             <include layout="@layout/item_toolbar_main"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This will work. I have used the `<include>` but alternatively you can just copy and paste the whole `View` from layout `item_toolbar_main` to the inside of the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` instead of `<include layout="@layout/item_toolbar_main">`.

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected.

Comment: **Happy Coding!** @ManOfWar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace... why you don't just call setSupportActionBar(theNewToolbar) to replace it?

Comment: I have already done it. Check MainActivivty  setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);